# jQuery set div width to closest variable like snapTo

Tags: jquery

I'm working on project where I want to modified **#screen** width to closest width of other (div.snapcord)

My DOM is something like this...

HTML :

```
<div id="iphone3" class="snapcord"></div>
<div id="iphone4" class="snapcord"></div>
<div id="ipad" class="snapcord"></div>

<div id="screen"></div>
```

CSS

```
#iphone3 { width: 320px }
#iphone4 { width: 480px }
#ipad { width: 768px }
```

**#screen** has dynamic width anything between 300px to 780px. I want **#screen** width **snapTo** closest width of other (div.snapcord) with **snapTolerance of 5px**;

Say,

**#screen** width is **315px** OR **325px** then I want to modify it to **320px**

**#screen** width is **475px** OR **485px** then I want to modify it to **480px**

**#screen** width is **763px** OR **773px** then I want to modify it to **768px** (**snapTolerance of 5px** only )

Else, leave **#screen** width to its original value.

I'm learning jQuery & have managed to get width of each div.snapcord using following snippet.

```
$('.snapcord').each(function() {
   var getWidth = $(this).width();
   alert(getWidth);
});
```

But I'm not clear about how to move further..

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNZjQ/1/)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I really get it, but isn't this what media queries are for?

Comment: How is the width of `#screen` changed? If your are attempting to create a responsive design, a better approach is CSS media queries.

Comment: It's not related to responsive design.. I want to create something like jQuery UI draggable snapTo..

Comment: So basically, what you want to do is get the average of two numbers in (for lack of a better word), 'chunks' of five?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var sW = $('#screen').width();
    sW = sW>=315 && sW<=325 ? 320 : sW;
    sW = sW>=375 && sW<=385 ? 480 : sW;
    sW = sW>=763 && sW<=773 ? 768 : sW;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LNZjQ/2/)

EDIT: 
something like this would be more dynamic

```
var sW = $("#screen").width(),

$('.snapcord').each(function() {
 var W = $(this).width();
    sW = sW>=W-5 && sW<=W+5 ? W : sW;
});
```

Comment: That's perfect !! But is it possible to get sW value using $('.snapcord').each(function() {
   var getWidth = $(this).width();
}); 
rather than defining evrytime like...
sW = sW>=315 && sW<=325 ? 320 : sW;
.... ??

Comment: Well, sure! You can replace any number with a variable. What it does is just to check if sW is between the two numbers, if so it sets it to the number after the questionmark, if not it sets it to sW (i.e. unchanged).